# Controlling robot servo arm (in real-time) via 3d model in blender

Tags: python, scripting, bones, inverse-kinematics, external-applications

I am trying to create and control a robot arm (made of servos) via it's 3D model.

I am big fan of [Justin Dailey's](http://justindailey.blogspot.com/2011/03/real-time-controlled-robotic-arm.html) work -- he was one of the first few people to accomplish this but his 7 year old dropbox links to his files are inaccessible.

I have been searching for days and have looked everywhere and tried almost everything but still can't even get one servo to move.

This [link](https://hackaday.io/project/9851-controlling-a-robot-arm-with-blender) has code for another type of robot arm but it doesn't work.

If anyone has a copy of Justin Dailey's files or knows how to control arduino connected servo via blender, could you please help?

Comment: That was done in blender 2.49. I would be stunned if the code still worked, even if it could be located.

Comment: The best place to start is with how to control your servos from *outside* Blender - eg, via Python. Once that’s established - and you have full control - the next step is how to control them from within Blender and how to tie them to your scene.